# How to search string by column wise in text file using autoit

Tags: autoit

I have a text file contains 2 columns, I need to search "A" using autoit

```
Column1 Column2
------- --------  
   1        2
   3        A
   5        6
```

Comment: see http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_ArraySearch.htm

Comment: Thanx, but how can I assign second column dynamically

Answer (score 3):

```
$file = FileRead("columns.txt")
$lines = StringSplit($file, @CR)
$count = $lines[0]

For $i = 1 To $count
   $line = $lines[$i]
   $noExtraBlanks = StringStripWS($line, 7)
   $columns = StringSplit($noExtraBlanks, " ")
   $columnCount = $columns[0]

   For $j = 1 To $columnCount
      If $columns[$j] == "A" Then
         ConsoleWrite("Line: " & $i & ", Column: " & $j & @CR)
      EndIf
   Next
Next
```

If you need more help, you need to be more precise what you exactly want to achieve... This here will give you the position of the "A" in the given file.